# WCF Load Testing

Tags: wcf, testing, binding, tcp, load

I am using WCF service with TCP binding and want to do load testing, can anybody please guide, how to perform it and i want to do it on free tool. I tried with VS 2010 but it didnt work because of TCP binding

Comment: Have you tried to setup a console application and access the service from there? With that you can execute parallel calls to the service to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend a different approach to your load testing plan. Add a wsHttpBinding endpoint to your services and use something like [this free tool to do the load testing over HTTP instead of TCP.](http://wcfloadtest.codeplex.com/) The netTcpBinding will virtually always be faster than the HTTP based bindings but not nearly as dramatically as you'd think and probably not enough to make your load test results inaccurate.

With the HTTP based load tests you'll have more options for tools to use. Remember that you are trying to determine the performance profile of your code not the WCF framework itself. You'll still want to do some results validation with the netTcpBinding using something along the lines of what @PeytonCrow mentions in his comment to the question.

Comment: thanks Sixto it could be one of the worthy alternate.. but is there any tool which support tcp binding?

Comment: There is a commercial product [named SO-Aware Workbench](http://www.tellagostudios.com/products/so-aware-test-workbench%E2%84%A2) that has a load testing component. It seems to support all WCF bindings but you'll need to try to know for sure.